# UPDATE Query Multiple fields, multiple conditions

Tags: select, sql-update, ms-access-2010, sql-insert

This is an MS Access related post.

How can I change the INSERT INTO statement to an UPDATE Statement?

```
            DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO A_tblStagingTablesChecksHEADERS (Header, Header2) " _
                & "SELECT DISTINCT(SELECT F1 FROM tblStagingIssuerNames_ReverseRepos " _
                & "WHERE F1 = 'ISSUER CODE') as F1data, " _
                & "(SELECT F51 FROM tblStagingIssuerNames_ReverseRepos " _
                & "WHERE F51 = 'INSTRUMENT REFERENCE (BOE)') as F2data " _
                & "FROM tblStagingIssuerNames_ReverseRepos;"
```

I have tried the below (unsuccessful):

```
    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE A_tblStagingTablesChecksHEADERS, tblStagingIssuerNames_ReverseRepos " _
                & "SELECT DISTINCT(SELECT F1 FROM tblStagingIssuerNames_ReverseRepos " _
                & "WHERE F1 = 'ISSUER CODE') as F1data, " _
                & "SELECT DISTINCT(SELECT F51 FROM tblStagingIssuerNames_ReverseRepos " _
                & "WHERE F51 = 'INSTRUMENT REFERENCE (BOE)') as F2data " _
                & "FROM tblStagingIssuerNames_ReverseRepos," _
                & "SET A_tblStagingTablesChecksHEADERS.Header = F1data, " _
                & "SET A_tblStagingTablesChecksHEADERS.Header2 = F2data;"
```

For both statements (with and without aliases), I get Run-time error '3075':

> Syntax error in query expression '(SELECT DISTINCT(SELECT F1 FROM tblStagingIssuerNames_ReverseRepos WHERE F1 = 'ISSUER CODE'))'.

Answer (score 0):

You are using invalid Update statement syntax. Try this:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE A_tblStagingTablesChecksHEADERS " _
            & "SET Header = (SELECT DISTINCT F1 FROM tblStagingIssuerNames_ReverseRepos " _
            & "WHERE F1 = 'ISSUER CODE'), " _
            & "Header2 = (SELECT DISTINCT F51 FROM tblStagingIssuerNames_ReverseRepos " _
            & "WHERE F51 = 'INSTRUMENT REFERENCE (BOE)')";
```

Comment: @ Rono Thank you for your response. I believe the Aliases are mandatory. I have tried adding them in and out of the brackets of your script but still got the syntax error message.

Comment: Aliases are not needed in an UPDATE statement.  I can see how you could get an error message if either of the inner select statements return more than one record, but I would need to know the error message you are getting.

Comment: @ Rono, the initial SELECT statements used for this piece did retrieve multiple records  (actually the number of records the underlying table holds) and that's the reason why I added DISTINCT. Using DISTINCT I get a single record. I will add the description of the error I get in my post.

Comment: @ProtoVB, I should have looked at that more closely.  I updated my answer so that the syntax should be correct.

Comment: The statement does now run... but retrieves 0 data! I do not understand that. if I only run the SELECT statement then I get a value for each field!! What's wrong there?

Comment: Technically UPDATE statements don't retrieve any data.  But assuming the data you expected to be changed has not been changed, since I don't know the data involved, I can't say at this point why it's not working.